# Scale-able and secure structure for nodejs express angularjs and orientdb application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, orientdb

I am working on a these four packages
OrientDB + NodeJS + Express + AngularJS
and i want to build a scale-able system architecture. Which should
Scale-able and easy to maintain.
I also read and explore some system design techniques like mean.io mean.js angular-seed etc
but the structure i liked more is mean.io BUT the problem is this mean.io is using mongoDB(mongoose and mongodb driver ) And I want to use orientDB.

So
Can you help me about 
1 :- Structure of the system
2 :- BEST development environment for my development stack

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how easy it is to integrate Sails.js with angularJS but a possible route is:

- AngularJS (potentially through [angular-sails](https://github.com/janpantel/angular-sails))
- Sails.js

  - uses Express
  - [waterline-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb) adapter
- OrientDB

That would get you there and all these projects are well maintained.